# Best practice to handle Appstore approval when you are migrating to new server APIs

Tags: ios, iphone, migration, appstore-approval

We are online service with a server, web app, and iPhone app. We are going to migrate to new APIs on our server.
The problem we face is how to embed Apple review into migration process.

Without Apple review we would do it this way:

1. Stop our service for an hour for maintenance.
2. Migrate database with user data
3. Release new version of web app with new APIs
4. Release new version of iPhone app with new APIs
5. Close maintenance. Open our service for use.

We keep both old APIs and new APIs on the server. Old APIs are needed to work with those users who would not download the latest iPhone app.

However, Apple review ruins this process.  We need to provide Apple with access to a demo account. It means that step 4 above is delayed for the time of review ( a week or more). It means that users will get web app with new functionality but actually, couldn’t use it as soon as Apple approve iPhone app.

Please advise how do you deal with such case?

Comment: Can you keep both just for the review? after the aproval, discart the files, and do the process shutting down the older server.

Comment: @UlyssesR Could you please clarify what do you mean when you say "keep both"? APIs (old / new)? Or web app (old / new)? Or iPhone (old / new)?

Comment: old and new API running at the same time, in your system you can do that?

Comment: Yes, and we do it for those users who would not uprade to new iPhone app. If do not to take to the account Apple review, the overall structure would be: A)  an Old iPnone app (users who wouldn't upgrade) - Old server APIs - New Web app (can't use new functionality). B) New iPhone app (user who would upgrade )  - New server APIs - New Web app

Comment: Why don't you just deploy the new API before you submit the app for review?  You are going to have to keep the old API anyway, as you say, so old apps will continue to use the old API, Apple will test with the new API and then when the app is released people who uograde will start using the new API too

Comment: You will just need to have a configuration  to disable the new web app features while allowing the new API for the app

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for advice. If I understand you right, you propose to have web app working with both old and new API. Doing so we support current users who use old iPhone app (Old iPhone app - Web app with new and old APIs), support Apple review (New iPhone app - Web app with new and old APIs) and after approval (Old iPhone / New iPhone - Web app with new and old APIs). Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Obviously I am not aware of what your web app is but it should be possible to support the new API without changing the web app and then after approval you can make changes to the web app if required. You can also manually release your app for download at any point after approval so you can plan your change

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, this approach is valid. Th only thing we did not make our web app to support both Old and New APIs to save development time. The plan was to have separate versions of web app: current one with Old APIs and new one wit NEW APIs. (The same like old and new iPhone app working only with old or new APIs). And keep only the server working with both versions of APIs. Now we see the issue and try to figure out if we can save the time not to develop the web app version just to go through Apple review. Because this version is in no use once new  iPhone app is released

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

- Keep your old service (A) on, as usual
- Start a new service (B)
- Migrate database with user data from (A) to (B)
- Submit new version of iPhone app with new APIs (B) with "Manual release".
- Wait till Apple reviews your app
- Once the app is approved, then you should stop the service (A) **(from now on, this is maintenance mode time)**
- Repeat migration of the database from (A) to (B), so data in (B) is up-to-date.
- Release new version of web app with new APIs in (B)
- Release your iPhone app
- The iPhone app will be distributed in less than 24 hours (usually). **(maintenance mode is over)**

The problem here is how you may deal with older iPhone app versions. I understand this is your first release. You should somehow be able to activate a "maintenance mode" for your iPhone app and a versioning system for that too.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer is very clear and visual. Great! Am I right that in your solution you propose two servers (one for A and one for B) and two databases (one for A and one for B)? Currently, we use one server with APIs A and B and one database.

Comment: Yes. It presupposes two concurrent databases and two APIs, either in one single server or in two servers. (Though the simplest solution would be using two servers).

Comment: Alternatively, after the Apple approval you could simply shut down service (B) and flip the upgrade switch on service (A) and release the updated client, avoiding having to migrate the DB.